# How to iterate over a list and create hyperlinks based on the text in thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I am developing a food website using Spring boot, Thymleaf and Bootstrap. I need to display menu items in a webpage. To display it I am fetching the data from a database and then iterating over it to display. However, I am not able to display it in a single column like this. Any suggestions on how to handle this?

[image: I need to display like this]

**Code:**

${menu.mainMenuName}"

Comment: This the code i am using to iterate:

<div class="col-md-2">
 <a class="text-info" th:each="menu: ${mainMenu}" th:value="${menu.id}" th:text="${menu.mainMenuName}" href="">${menu.mainMenuName}"</a>
</div>

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and add your formatted code there, instead of showing it in a comment (where it is not easy to read). Take a look at the [Markdown Help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), also, if needed, for formatting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a link from two parts in thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769571/how-to-create-a-link-from-two-parts-in-thymeleaf)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your "th:each" statement to the div tag. It will be something like:

```
  <div th:each="menu: ${mainMenu}" class="col-md-12">
     
     <a class="text-info"  th:value="${menu.id}" th:text="${menu.mainMenuName}" href=""></a>
    
  </div>
```

Note that ${menu.mainMenuName}"  is redundant with th:text="${menu.mainMenuName}

Comment: But now links are getting displayed in a single line whereas i want it to be displayed in a column like structure as shown in my image.

Comment: I have changed the class from col-md-2 to col-md-12. Following instructions from: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp  . This should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for it. Problem with my previous approach was it was creating col-md-2 for every link hence it was getting displayed in single line to fix it below approach was followed:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="main-menu" th:each="menu: ${mainMenu}">
                <a class="text-info"  th:value="${menu.id}" th:text="${menu.mainMenuName}" href=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```